# Getting all the corresponding rows with max date in r

Tags: r, max

I have the data frame similar to this but with 30 more variables

[image: Data frame]

i need only the corresponding values of max date for each "code" 
so the output should be like this

[image: Required form]

Any experts can help me solving this please .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can also be done using `dplyr` (assuming your data is a data frame called `dt`):

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% group_by(code) %>% filter(Date == max(Date))
```

Comment: Hi David,thanks so much it worked .Could you please explain how does the code works

Comment: The first thing is the use of the "pipe", `%>%`, which enables you to chain commands. This makes the code easier to write and read. So, you start with specifying the name of the data frame, and this "piped" to the next command in the chain, `group_by`. This command splits the data into chunks based on the value of `code`, so all subsequent commands in the chain work on one chunk at a time, with the results being combined in the data that is returned. `filter` is used to select rows in the data based on the condition, so the row that corresponds to the latest date in each chunk is selected.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'code', we `order` the 'Date' descendingly and get the first row with `head`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(-as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')), head(.SD, 1), by = code]
#       code bill      Date Type Month   KM
#1: C111574885   50 9/25/2015  red     9 1070
#2: C111519730  200 6/25/2015 blue     6  350
#3: D100000468   40  6/4/2015  red     6 1240
#4: D100000470  500 3/13/2015  red     3 1000
```

Or after `order`ing we can use `unique` `by` 'code' to get the first row (which will have the max date).

```
unique(setDT(df1)[order(code, -as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y'))], by = 'code')
#  bill       code      Date Type Month   KM
#1:  200 C111519730 6/25/2015 blue     6  350
#2:   50 C111574885 9/25/2015  red     9 1070
#3:   40 D100000468  6/4/2015  red     6 1240
#4:  500 D100000470 3/13/2015  red     3 1000
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(bill = c(100, 200, 500, 900, 150, 50, 40), 
code = c("C111519730", 
"C111519730", "D100000470", "C111574885", "C111574885", "C111574885", 
"D100000468"), Date = c("4/9/2015", "6/25/2015", "3/13/2015", 
"1/9/2015", "9/20/2015", "9/25/2015", "6/4/2015"), Type = c("red", 
"blue", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "red"), Month = c(4, 6, 
3, 1, 9, 9, 6), KM = c(100, 350, 1000, 450, 900, 1070, 1240)),
 .Names = c("bill", 
"code", "Date", "Type", "Month", "KM"),
 row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Sotos Yes, it should also work, but `order` might be faster

Comment: this solution is super slow.

Comment: @marbel You could make it faster with `.I` instead of subseting with `.SD`

Comment: i.e.    `setDT(df1)[df1[order(-as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')), .I[1], by = code]$V1]`

Comment: @marbel also, if you are comparing with the `==` with `max`, yes, it would be slow as it is also doing an ordering here

Comment: Right, that's what I was doing. But with .I it's running fast enough! I can't notice the difference really. So basically the inside call just returns the indexes, right?

Comment: @marbel yes, it return just the indexes in another column (default columns are named starting wtih 'V1'.  So we extract that `$V1`.