# Get the max date based on multiple columns of an R dplyr / tidyverse dataframe

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse

From a csv file that looks like this:

| Date | Timestamp | Units | Name | Condition | Obj | Param | Attrib1 | Atrrib2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-07-31 | 2019-08-01 01:16:09 | m3 | n01 | a1 | o1 | Nap | TP | IN | 34937 |
| 2019-07-31 | 2019-08-01 01:16:10 | m3 | n01 | a2 | o2 | Nap | TP | OUT | 36673.09 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:06 | mg/l | n01 | a3 | o3 | NO3 | TP | OUT | 1 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:06 | mg/l | n01 | z5 | o4 | BOD | IO | IN | 220 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:06 | mg/l | n01 | z5 | o4 | BOD | TP | IN | 220 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:06 | mg/l | n01 | z6 | o1 | NO2 | TP | OUT | 0.31 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:13 | mg/l | n01 | a11 | o4 | Ntot | IO | IN | 47 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:13 | mg/l | n01 | a11 | o4 | Ntot | TP | IN | 47 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-07 02:15:06 | m3 | n01 | a1 | o1 | Nap | TP | IN | 17909 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-07 02:15:07 | m3 | n01 | a2 | o2 | Nap | TP | OUT | 19216.19 |

I want to remove the rows with the last (or max) **Timestamp** per value in column **Date** and column **Condition**. 
The resulting table should not have the duplicated timestamps "2019-11-18 20:21:06" and "2019-11-18 20:21:13" (Which **Condition** and **Result** values were [z5, a11] and [220, 47] respectively).

| Date | Timestamp | Units | Name | Condition | Obj | Param | Attrib1 | Atrrib2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-07-31 | 2019-08-01 01:16:09 | m3 | n01 | a1 | o1 | Nap | TP | IN | 34937 |
| 2019-07-31 | 2019-08-01 01:16:10 | m3 | n01 | a2 | o2 | Nap | TP | OUT | 36673.09 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:06 | mg/l | n01 | a3 | o3 | NO3 | TP | OUT | 1 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:06 | mg/l | n01 | z5 | o4 | BOD | IO | IN | 220 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:06 | mg/l | n01 | z6 | o1 | NO2 | TP | OUT | 0.31 |
| 2019-11-06 | 2019-11-18 20:21:13 | mg/l | n01 | a11 | o4 | Ntot | IO | IN | 47 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-07 02:15:06 | m3 | n01 | a1 | o1 | Nap | TP | IN | 17909 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-07 02:15:07 | m3 | n01 | a2 | o2 | Nap | TP | OUT | 19216.19 |

I found two links ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861391/remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-multiple-columns-using-dplyr-tidyverse) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509498/getting-all-the-corresponding-rows-with-max-date-in-r)) to come up with the following R script

```
library(tidyverse)
# Group per Date and Condition and filter max Timestamp
df <- read.csv("./Example.csv") %>%
    mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
    mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%
    group_by(Date, Condition) %>%
    filter(Timestamp == max(Timestamp)) %>%
    distinct()
write_csv(df, file = "./ExampleResult.csv")
```

But I cannot get the wished results. 
What is wrong with the approach? Is there any other easier way?
Thank you!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show example data instead of images

Comment: If you don't want duplicate rows, use `slice_max(Timestamp, n = 1)` instead of the `filter`

Comment: Thank you Dan Adams  and Ronak Shah, both answers do the job. I liked the approach suggested by Dan becasue it could be more versatile in other situations when extra conditions are needed.

Comment: @eliasmaxil - glad it helps. Feel free to [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that was most helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple values at `max(Timestamp)`. To resolve this I'd suggest to use `dplyr::slice_max` and setting `with_ties = FALSE`.

Here's some code to get what you're after.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(Date, Condition) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = Timestamp, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE)
```

But depending on your application, you may want to be explicit about how to resolve those ties by supplying additional variables to the `order_by` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following :

```
library(dplyr)

read.csv("./Example.csv") %>%
#df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), 
        Timestamp = as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  distinct(Date, Condition, Result, .keep_all = TRUE) -> result

result

#        Date           Timestamp Units Name Condition Obj Param Attrib1 Atrrib2   Result
#1 2019-07-31 2019-08-01 01:16:09    m3  n01        a1  o1   Nap      TP      IN 34937.00
#2 2019-07-31 2019-08-01 01:16:10    m3  n01        a2  o2   Nap      TP     OUT 36673.09
#3 2019-11-06 2019-11-18 20:21:06  mg/l  n01        a3  o3   NO3      TP     OUT     1.00
#4 2019-11-06 2019-11-18 20:21:06  mg/l  n01        z5  o4   BOD      IO      IN   220.00
#5 2019-11-06 2019-11-18 20:21:06  mg/l  n01        z6  o1   NO2      TP     OUT     0.31
#6 2019-11-06 2019-11-18 20:21:13  mg/l  n01       a11  o4  Ntot      IO      IN    47.00
#7 2021-01-06 2021-01-07 02:15:06    m3  n01        a1  o1   Nap      TP      IN 17909.00
#8 2021-01-06 2021-01-07 02:15:07    m3  n01        a2  o2   Nap      TP     OUT 19216.19
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2019-07-31", "2019-07-31", "2019-11-06", 
"2019-11-06", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-06", 
"2021-01-06", "2021-01-06"), Timestamp = c("2019-08-01 01:16:09", 
"2019-08-01 01:16:10", "2019-11-18 20:21:06", "2019-11-18 20:21:06", 
"2019-11-18 20:21:06", "2019-11-18 20:21:06", "2019-11-18 20:21:13", 
"2019-11-18 20:21:13", "2021-01-07 02:15:06", "2021-01-07 02:15:07"
), Units = c("m3", "m3", "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", 
"mg/l", "m3", "m3"), Name = c("n01", "n01", "n01", "n01", "n01", 
"n01", "n01", "n01", "n01", "n01"), Condition = c("a1", "a2", 
"a3", "z5", "z5", "z6", "a11", "a11", "a1", "a2"), Obj = c("o1", 
"o2", "o3", "o4", "o4", "o1", "o4", "o4", "o1", "o2"), Param = c("Nap", 
"Nap", "NO3", "BOD", "BOD", "NO2", "Ntot", "Ntot", "Nap", "Nap"
), Attrib1 = c("TP", "TP", "TP", "IO", "TP", "TP", "IO", "TP", 
"TP", "TP"), Atrrib2 = c("IN", "OUT", "OUT", "IN", "IN", "OUT", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "OUT"), Result = c(34937, 36673.09, 1, 220, 
220, 0.31, 47, 47, 17909, 19216.19)),class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```